# TikZ - draw angled lines until the same x-coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, line, angle

I'm going to use an example. Consider this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[->] (0,0) -- ++(30:3);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- ++(40:3);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- ++(50:3);
    
    \draw[dashed] (2,0) -- (2,3);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: !(https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)]

I want the long of the angled lines not to be specified, but until that "imaginary" vertical dashed line. I know I could do the math and get exactly the point where I want my lines to land, but I just want to make it way easier. By the way, I want the arrow tips, not only the line, and I must use angled lines. Also, I don't want the imaginary line to appear, I used here just to clear my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use of the `intersections` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
   \path[ name path=L1] (O) -- ++(30:3);
    \path[name path=L2] (O) -- ++(40:3);
    \path[name path=L3] (O) -- ++(50:4);
    \path[name path=vert] (2,0) -- (2,3);
    
\path [name intersections={of=L1 and vert,by={A}}];
\path [name intersections={of=L2 and vert,by={B}}];
\path [name intersections={of=L3 and vert,by={C}}];
\draw [->](O)--(A);
\draw [->](O)--(B);
\draw [->](O)--(C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```